# Collapse boolean vector with AND or OR

Tags: r

Really simple, but I struggle to collapse a boolean vector. `AND(c(T,T,F))` seems to do the trick for AND, but `OR(c(T,T,F))` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`all()` and `any()` seem to be doing the trick.